# why is my flask API project can't run, am trying to run it through my window command line but am receiving erros

Tags: flask

Usage: python -m flask run [OPTIONS]
Try `python -m flask run --help` for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\Dreams Reality\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dreams Reality\Desktop\api\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields
  File "C:\Users\Dreams Reality\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import fields, reqparse, apidoc, inputs, cors
  File "C:\Users\Dreams Reality\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\fields.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug import cached_property
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'werkzeug' (C:\Users\Dreams Reality\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py)
```

I tried running my flask project using `python -m flask run`
I expected to take a good look at my project on localhost,
And am getting this:

Try `python -m flask run --help` for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\Dreams Reality\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dreams Reality\Desktop\api\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields
  File "C:\Users\Dreams Reality\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import fields, reqparse, apidoc, inputs, cors
  File "C:\Users\Dreams Reality\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\fields.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug import cached_property
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'werkzeug' (C:\Users\Dreams Reality\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like some of your packages aren't compatible with each other.
try checking your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

`flask-restplus` does not appear to have been updated for several years[1]. Since then, Werkzeug moved `cached_property`[2].

In your position, I'd drop `flask-restplus` and either choose an actively maintained rest package for flask, or roll your own.

[1] https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus
[2] https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/changes/

Comment: Ok lem me check this out thanks for your assistance